# Inserting a component/embedded view as first child of ViewContainerRef that has children in the component's template

Tags: angular

I'm trying to dynamically insert an embedded view based on an `<ng-template>` to a `ViewContainerRef` in a base component.

That base component contains fields that are relevant to all implementations of that base component. I need extend that component by dynamically creating components/templates and inserting them into that component's view.

I've noticed that if my `ViewContainerRef` already contains children, then the component/view created with `createComponent()`/`createEmbeddedView()` is always inserted as the last child of the `ViewContainerRef`'s element. I want the inserted view to be the **first child** of the `ViewContainerRef`'s element.

Is there any way to achieve this besides manipulating the DOM outside of Angular?

Example app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t6ygjl

Comment: The ViewContainerRef `insert` method accepts an optional parameter that controls the index of insertion. Would that be an option for you? for example: `container.insert(content, 0);`